# ng build not executing successfully for my angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

- I am trying to learn js and angular
- I installed angular cli.
- after that I ran ng build --prod.
- but still i am getting below error.
  Cannot read property 'config' of null
- I googled for that error but not sure how to fix it
- providing error and code below.
- i installed proper versions for angular..
- providing that below

  jkaksjkjsakj webcomponent/src/main/webapp (r1-rts)

  **$ npm install @angular/core@2.3.1 --save**
          sports@1.0.0 C:\isdiuui\webcomponent\src\main\webapp
          +-- @angular/core@2.3.1
          +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
          `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.6.25

  ```
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
  npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.10 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.4.10 but none was installed.
  npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.10 but none was installed.
  npm WARN @angular/core@2.3.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
  npm WARN @angular/core@2.3.1 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
  npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
  npm WARN license-webpack-plugin@1.1.0 requires a peer of webpack-sources@>= 1.0.0 but none was installed.
  npm WARN sports@1.0.0 No description
  npm WARN sports@1.0.0 No repository field.
  ```

ng build error

```
jkaksjkjsakj webcomponent/src/main/webapp (r1-rts)
$ ng build --prod
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (C:\isdiuui\webcomponent\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\build.js:15:56)
    at Class.run (C:\isdiuui\webcomponent\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:204:26)
    at resolve (C:\isdiuui\webcomponent\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:261:20)
    at Class.validateAndRun (C:\isdiuui\webcomponent\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:240:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\isdiuui\webcomponent\src\main\webapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:140:24)
```

ng version

```
jkaksjkjsakj webcomponent/src/main (r1-rts)
$ ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.7
node: 6.11.2
os: win32 x64
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sports",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"karma start karma.conf.js\""
  },
  "license": "hhjjh",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "latest-version": "^2.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "jasmine-expect": "^3.0.1",
    "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jquery": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: try to upgrade your package.json file to angular 4.

Comment: @SathishKotha hey is it not possible to achieve with angular 2.3.1 ...sinc emy entire angular application was developed in angular 2 and not in angular 4

Comment: not sure. your using latest cli version 1.4.7, its new version for angular 4, but your are using angular 2.3.1. just give a try. there is no much changes  in angular 4 compare to angular 2

Comment: And your angular packages are not unique. please change it to unique version for @angular. core is 2.3.1 and remaining 2.0.0. https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc-angular-4/blob/master/package.json

Comment: @SathishKotha can you update in my code...its so confusing

Comment: it is sounds like there is a significant versions mismatch of your project local cli and global cli. Run `ng -v` outside your project root and you will see your global cli version.

Comment: For angular 2.3.1 do you know what version of cli we need to use